# MouseEvent.path equivalent in Firefox & Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer 1.0 and when there is a click on a button in Chrome a `MouseEvent` is generated. This `MouseEvent` object has a `path` property which is an ordered array of parent elements to the clicked button. In Firefox & Safari, however, a `click` is generated which does not have a `path` property. Is there an equivalent property of the `click` object which gives me the same information?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's not available, but if you really would like to have this property, then you could extend the native prototype of the Event object like so:

```
if (!("path" in Event.prototype))
Object.defineProperty(Event.prototype, "path", {
  get: function() {
    var path = [];
    var currentElem = this.target;
    while (currentElem) {
      path.push(currentElem);
      currentElem = currentElem.parentElement;
    }
    if (path.indexOf(window) === -1 && path.indexOf(document) === -1)
      path.push(document);
    if (path.indexOf(window) === -1)
      path.push(window);
    return path;
  }
});
```

However if I were you, I wouldn't extend the prototype - I would create a function like mentioned above instead.

Also I would change Event.prototype to MouseEvent.prototype if you want to cover only those types of events.

Comment: Awesomesauce. Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but solves my issue perfectly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, @wogsland, what answer, or type of answer, were you hoping for?

Comment: I thought there would be an equivalent property in the object created in Firefox whose name I just hadn't guessed yet.

Comment: @wogsland You could combine this answer with a check for the existence of Event.prototype.composedPath and get the best of both worlds: maximum compatibility with this code only executed in IE/Edge.

Answer (score 41):

It seems like the [e.composedPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) method might be a cross-browser version of `e.path`. It works in Chrome and Firefox. Not sure about Safari.

Comment: Perfect. Works in all three.

Comment: Note that it does not work on Edge or IE: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_event_composedpath

Comment: It's now supported in Edge! https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_event_composedpath

Comment: @Splaktar Works in Edge.